# Dynamic measure based on x axis power bi

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax, powerbi-custom-visuals

I have a table that's structured similar to the following:
[image]

I'm using power bi to analyse the score based on the different characteristic columns using the following formula:
gender_total=calculate(sumx(values(mytable[Gender]),mytable[score]))
which returns the following graph values (for gender):
[image]

My actual table has over 20 characteristic columns, is it possible to make this measure dynamic
so that it depends on the graph x axis values i.e. instead of creating a measure for each characteristic, i can have a general measure which calculates the total score for any characteristic. E.g. if the graph x axis is age then it'll use age and calculate the total per age

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to. Have a simple measure like:

```
Total Score = SUM(mytable[score])
```

And Power BI will do the rest.

Comment: Any follow-up? Otherwise please help Accept the answer for the benefit of all.